# Ant script for GitHub authentication to clone a git repo?

Tags: git, ant

```
<sshexec host = "https://github.com/sidhuboby/test-1" username = 

"*********@gmail.com" password = "*****" command = "git clone *******

******"/>
```

will this authentication step work github repoauthentication in Ant script.

Comment: Is it really your intention to run `git clone` remotely on github's server? I have a feeling you're just trying to clone a repository to your own machine. In that case just use Ant's `<exec>` task with `executable="git"`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will for sure not work. You are trying to SSH into GitHub and then on the GitHub server execut the Git command. This will not work. The only user that is allowed to SSH to GitHub is the user `git` and which actual end-user it is, is determined by the SSH key used to authenticate. Authenticating with username and password will not work.

And even if you would connect as user Git with your SSH key, you would not be able to execute the clone command - which also wouldn't help much on the GitHub servers - but also get a message displayed that tells you as whom you identified and that GitHub is not providing an interactive shell service.

Comment: How would I clone , using the some Ant script ?

Comment: But if I want to clone from the git repo, with out authenticating how can I clone the git repo ?

Comment: Git (or SSH if you use an SSH URL and SSH keys) does the authentication.

Comment: My intention was actually to clone the git repo using ant script locally, once clone is done i have to deploy those files on the sandboxes. but, i'm struct with the cloning step.

Comment: There are many ways. One or to use the Ant tasks of JGit: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Ant_Tasks